# Button text color not changing on over

Tags: html, css, hover

I am using the following code to have both span and color change on hover in my button. However, towards the edges, the color of the text again goes back to blue (the initial color). Ideally it should be white like it is when hovered in center of the button.

Also the borders on the button have the same problem. If someone could help me in this, it would be really appreciated.

```css
.outer2 {
  margin: 0px;
}

.button1 {
  border: 2px solid #00338d;
  border-radius: 12px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #00338d 50%, white 50%);
  background-size: 200% 200%;
  background-position: bottom left;
  transition: all .4s ease-out;
}

.button1:hover {
  background-position: top left;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.text1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #00338d;
  transition: all .4s ease-out;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.outer2 a:hover {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

.text1:hover {
  color: white;
}

.button1 {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button1:after {
  content: '\2913';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 12px;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  color: white;
}

.button1:hover {
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  color: white;
}

.button1:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 10px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer2">
  <a class="component-link" href="#download" rel="noopener noreferrer">
    <div class="button1" style="vertical-align:middle">
      <div class=" text1">Download below</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have a syntax error in your HTML, you never close the `<a>` Tag

Answer (score 0):

Change your

```
  .text1:hover {
    color: white;  
  }
```

to

```
 .button1:hover .text1 {
    color: white;  
  }
```

this will add the 'color: white' every time you are hoverin on the button, instead of hovering on the text like it was before. This should fix your problem